# Cannot use my model data in javascript

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

Could you please help me find what I am doing wrong?

My model has a string[] field called AllKnownColors. I am trying to use it in my javascript code like this:

```
    var clrs = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Model.AllKnownColors)');
```

But it doesn't work. The debugger shows me this:

```
var clrs = JSON.parse('System.String[]');
```

and the following error:   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token S

And I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: What would you have *liked* `@Html.Raw(Model.AllKnownColors)` to result in? As you can see, it turns into `"System.String[]"` when turned into a string (using `ToString()` internally as `Html.Raw()` does).

Comment: should tag this with asp related tags, issue isn't really javascript related

Comment: Could you please tell what would be the right way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Model.AllKnownColors` is a `string` array. `Html.Raw` accepts a single `string` as an argument. Since `Model.AllKnownColors` is not a `string`, C# framework calls the object's `ToString` method. By default, `ToString` returns the name of the object type.

If you are attempting to use a pure string of colors, you can do something like this instead:

```
var clrs = '@string.Join(", ", Model.AllKnownColors)';
```

If you actually want to turn `Model.AllKnownColors` into a JavaScript array, you can do this:

```
var clrs = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.AllKnownColors));
```

Note that in both cases, `JSON.parse` is unnecessary.

Comment: The last solution gives me an error: Returns markup that is not html encoded :(

Comment: I forgot the semi-colon on the end of the second example. However, that should not cause invalid "markup" regardless.

Comment: What is the error specifically? I do not receive an error when I compile this code myself. Also, it may be helpful if you provide a larger code snippet of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Raw() complained about the markup. I ignored it, and it seems like this actually gives me the data. :) Thanks.

Comment: Could you please tell why do I need json at all? I realized that can reach my model like this: @foreach(var color in Model.AllKnownColors)...

Comment: You did not provide a large enough code sample for me to judge if you actually needed to use JSON. You are perfectly capable of using the method you just described as well instead of JSON if that fits your scenario better.

Comment: I just needed to reach my model from javascript (in a partial view). Is it possible to say briefly in what scenario I would need JSON? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
var clrs = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Model.AllKnownColors)');
```

is similar to

```
var clrs = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Model.AllKnownColors.ToString())');
```

You need to convert Model.AllKnownColors to json. You can use [Newtonsoft JSON](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/json-serialization-using-newtonsoft-json-serialize/) for this purpose.

```
var clrs = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.AllKnownColors))');
```

Or you can write you own method for converting. Newtonsoft JSON is easy and good choice. Your own methods could be more fast.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. For some reason, I get "JsonConvert does not exist in the current context.

Comment: You need add references to Newtonsoft.Json. You can make with help of nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/.